# Ubuntu External HDD Login error

Tags: login, suspend, external-hdd

I have Ubuntu installed on my external hard drive. It runs pretty decently until I leave it for a minute. Once it comes out of suspension, it asks for my password. After entering my password, the input box disappears and I get a message saying I entered the incorrect password. After pushing the power button to restart my PC, Ubuntu logs in normally but I get a message saying I have an error. After reporting the error, none of my programs show up in the dash. Nothing short of reinstalling Ubuntu can fix this and after reinstalling it happens again! Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use standby, suspend or hibernate on Ubuntu. It does not work well on most computers, especially if ran from external hard drives. Odds are it didn't have time to dump the RAM onto it before shutting it down. Most likely it's because Ubuntu still can't properly implement none of the three features above. Don't suspend/standby/hibernate, you should be fine.